# Set a timeout for loading a file from an EBS share

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, timeout, nfs

So I have an interesting situation and I'm not sure how to get around it.

We have a process that takes an aggregate look at our sales data and then builds a graph via Google Chart. To keep from hammering the database (or Google for that matter) it only runs this every 30 minutes. It looks at the previous file to determine if it's hit the 30 minute threshold and, if so, it builds the new file. We have two servers behind a load balancer. So both servers have to have access to the same location to store this file. We did this using an EBS share, mounted via NFS (our entire setup is in AWS). This process works just fine.

The problem is sometimes the EBS share is slow or disconnected. This causes a ripple effect then, throughout our internal tools waiting on this one file to process (unless you turn the notice off). I've read a few threads (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165296/check-if-nfs-share-is-up-in-php)) that talk about [stream_set_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) but it's not clear how you would use that with loading a file (it's not exactly a stream) and I've been unable to find any examples.

Here's a snippet to give you an idea what the PHP file is doing

```
$file = '/ebs/path/to/image.png';
$newfile=false;
if(!is_file($file)) $newfile=true;
elseif(filemtime($file)+1800 < time()) {
    $newfile=true;
    unlink($file);
}
if(!$newfile){
    $i=imagecreatefrompng($file);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($file) + $timeout) . ' GMT');
    imagepng($i);
    imagedestroy($i);
    exit;
} else {
    // Build and output a new file here
}
```

How could I create a timeout for this script?

Comment: The root cause is "EBS is slow or disconnected", so the ultimate solution is to fix this. Whether AWS is up to the task is another question.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a solution to the problem than an answer to the question, but please post the output of `iostat -x 1` both when the server is running fine and when the file takes long to load. I've found that when the `avgqu-sz` goes above 30, even on IOPS-provisioned drives (ours are provisioned at 2000 IOPS) then EBS slows to a crawl. The solution is to try not to read or write to it for a second or three until the situation clears up.

Also, try cloning the volume and using the clone in place of the original volume. I've found that some AWS systems are just 'bad' and need to be replaced: this goes for EC2 instances, EBS volumes, RDS services, and others. Possibly that happens when luck brings you to use hardware running a VM with another user who may not be a good neighbour. Just cloning the resource and restarting it usually moves it to different hardware and resolves issues like this.

**EDIT:** Read [this great post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=124044#124044) about how to interpret `iostat` output, with an emphasis on how `iostat` pertains to EBS. I've read that a good dozen times.

Comment: I upvoted this (because it's very useful info) and gave it the bounty (for being the only answer submitted) but, as stated, it doesn't actually answer the question so I didn't flag it as such. I'd still like to see someone explain `stream_set_timeout`. But good info here nonetheless.